# Digit Frequency in C++ using a while loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the digit frequency of text entered using while loop. The code I used is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char c;
    int a[10] = {0};

    while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                a[0] += 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                a[1] += 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                a[2] += 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                a[3] += 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                a[4] += 1;
                break;
            case 5:
                a[5] += 1;
                break;
            case 6:
                a[6] += 1;
                break;
            case 7:
                a[7] += 1;
                break;
            case 8:
                a[8] += 1;
                break;
            case 9:
                a[9] += 1;
                break;                                  

        }


    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I am getting unusual value for the frequency of digits. Also, I have found many questions which are similar to mine but they use a different approach and I cannot understand what my mistake is.

Comment: What do you mean by 'unusual value'?

Comment: I don't know of *any* encoding where e.g. `1 == '1'`.

Comment: Also note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. This is important for a check you forget: Checking for `EOF`.

Comment: In C/C++ and many other languages, `char` is a numerical type. The C++ standard doesn't define exactly which numerical `char` values correspond to which written characters (though most implementations are close to ASCII). If you replace `case 0:` with `case '0':`, for example, you'll probably get the result you expect

Comment: you could use '0', '1' in your switch cases.

Comment: This is because `case 0:` means "check if the character was encoded as value 0", while `case '0':` means "check if the character is the same as the character '0'"

Comment: Lastly, The C and C++ specifications says that all digit characters must be encoded consecutively, starting with `'0'`. That means you can do e.g. `'1' - '0'` to get the integer value `1`.  Which you can use directly as an index instead of using a long `switch` statement.

Comment: @JMAA There is no such thing as "C/C++".

Comment: @NickyC By "C/C++" I just meant "C or C++", you are of course correct that I mistyped for the standard and have now fixed it

Comment: @JMAA Even "In C or C++ and many other languages" is logically and grammatically wrong. It should be "In C, C++, and many other languages".

Comment: @JMAA Thanks. Got my program working with those quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you are assuming that the encoding of '0' will be equal to the value 0. This is not the case.

Easiest fix is to slightly change your switch statement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char c;
    int a[10] = {0};

    while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
        switch (c) {
            case '0':
                a[0] += 1; break;
            case '1':
                a[1] += 1; break;
            case '2':
                a[2] += 1; break;
            case '3':
                a[3] += 1; break;
            case '4':
                a[4] += 1; break;
            case '5':
                a[5] += 1; break;
            case '6':
                a[6] += 1; break;
            case '7':
                a[7] += 1; break;
            case '8':
                a[8] += 1; break;
            case '9':
                a[9] += 1; break;                                  
        }
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Just forgot to put those quotes as I am using the char variable.

Answer (score 2):

Things that are wrong

1)   Using `getchar()` - which is a C I/O function - in C++.   Although permitted, it is formally discouraged.   It is also not guaranteed to work given `#include <iostream>` and, if it works with your compiler/library, you got lucky.      Use `std::cin.get()` instead.

2)   Both `getchar()` and `cin.get()` return an `int`.  Your code ignores that, and assigns the return value to a `char`.    Both functions can return a value that a `char` cannot represent, and do so to report errors.   Your code therefore ignores any errors that occur reading input.

3)   In standard C and C++, the character `'0'` cannot have the numeric value of `0`.   Your `switch`/`case` can ONLY work if `'0'` has a numeric value of `0`.   For example, in the ASCII character set, the character `'0'` has numeric value of `48` which is not equal to `0`   (and there are standardised character sets in which `'0'` has a different value than `48` (not `0`)).   Enough said.

4)   In standard C and C++, the characters representing digits `'0'`, `'1'`, ... `'9'` are consecutive.   There is also no standardised character set that has the digits non-consecutive.

To correct all of these wrong things.

1)   Store the return value of `cin.get()` into an `int`, and check it (e.g. to see if there is an error).

2)   Use the function `isdigit()` in standard header `<cctype>` to check if a character is a digit.   Bear in mind that `isdigit()` has undefined behaviour if given a value that cannot be represented in an `unsigned char`.

3)   Use the fact that digits are consecutive from `'0'`.

I'm not going to provide code, but you will find that working through ALL of these points will help fix your problem AND make your code easier to understand, and therefore easier to get right.

HINT:   it is not necessary to use a `switch` statement at all, unless you want longer and more error-prone code.  All that is necessary is to check that a character has been read correctly, and that it is a digit, and increment the corresponding array element.   That can be done using array syntax to increment a particular element of the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop using C and start using C++, then your code could be transormed to just a few line. Very simple.

There is a more or less standard approach for counting something in a container or in general.

We can use an associative container like a `std::map` (or a `std::unordered_map`). And here we associate a "key", in this case the "digit" to count, with a value, in this case the count of the specific digit.

And luckily the maps have a very nice index operator[]. This will look for the given key and, if found, return a reference to the value. If not found, then it will create a new entry with the key and return a reference to the new entry. So, in both cases, we will get a reference to the value used for counting. And then we can simply write:

```
std::map<char, int> counter{};
counter[c]++;
```

And that's it. More is not necessary. Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    //Our counter
    std::map<char, int> counter{};

    // Read characters from std::cin until '\n' is hit
    for (char c{}; (c = static_cast<char>(std::cin.get()))!='\n';)

        // If it was a digt, then count it
        if (std::isdigit(c))  counter[c]++;

    // Show result
    for (const auto& [digit, count] : counter) std::cout << digit << " --> " << count << '\n';
}
```

---

To be compiled with C++17